# how to use twilio webhook to reply to an sms in production

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, twilio

I am new to Twilio services and just started using their api for sms with `django`. the sms outbound work well and now i want to make sure to grab the value replied by the person who has received the message.

Locally, I have used `Ngrok` as a webhook, I provided the Ngrok URL generated while running my python application locally + backend api endpoint URL in the Twilio SMS settings required for the webhook and it work.

Please note that i made sure that the URL the SMS response is supposed to hit is publicly available.

Now my question is how do I make this work in a production environment where i cannot run `Ngrok` from my computer?

I removed the Ngrok URL provided since its not running locally and left the URL of the endpoint but i am not receiving anything back as a response.

PS: the endpoint created is publicly accessible to anyone even though it is hosted on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use PythonAnywhere! Directions are outlined in this [blog post by my coworker Miguel Grinberg](https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploying-python-webhooks-production-pythonanywhere). It’s easier to use than Heroku (which you could also use), and 100% focused on Python.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: unfortunately the infrastructure is hosted on AWS and i cant change it, any recommendation?

Comment: Can you update your question to include more about how you're using AWS? What URL of the endpoint are you using? Does AWS not show anything in the console where you're hosting?

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i did updated the bottom of the post to mention AWS but please note that its just that the entire application is hosted on AWS, otherwise the endpoint is publicly available, i cannot disclose it but anyone can hit that endpoint at the moment, any suggestion?